Normalize an angle in unity
How can I normalize angle between min value and max value?
like normalizing -1136316.78186234° between 0° , 360° or between 180° , 360°.
Node: for now I'm using double value as angle.
Thanks for reading.

When you say "normalize", do you mean that the result will be between 0 and 1? Also, how would you like to normalize an angle for a range when it doesn't fall inside that range, like normalizing 150° between 180° and 360°?

That's what the fmod function will do for you:
result = fmod(input, 360);

Having said that, consider not having the explicit angle in the first place. I prefer manipulating a sin/cos pair using the various trigonometric identities. That will not be affected by wrapping in this way.

Note that in C#, this would be written result = input % 360.0 as there's no top-level fmod function like there is in shader languages. This will however return a negative number for negative inputs, not in the 0-360° range that was requested.

For single-precision (32-bit) floats, you can use:
result = Mathf.Repeat(input, 360f);

or
result = 180f - Mathf.DeltaAngle(input, 180f);

These both take an input over any range and map it to the range [0, 360)
But since you're working with a double for the angle, you can peek at the implementation of Repeat to write equivalent double-precision code:
using System;

public class MathExtensions {

    public static double Wrap0_360(this double degrees)
    {
        return Math.Clamp(degrees - Math.Floor(degrees / 360.0) * 360.0, 0.0, 360.0);
    }
}

This lets you write myAngle = myAngle.Wrap0_360()

The question says "normalize", so shouldn't the result be converted to the range 0 - 1?

"Normalize" means to map into a standard range or to a standard magnitude. For many contexts, that range is [0, 1] (or [0, 1)), but for angles (-180°, 180°], [0°, 360°), (- π,  π], or [0, 2 π) are all common choices. The question explicitly requests [0°, 360°) as one of the proposed outputs.

I feel like "normalizing [...] between 0° , 360°" could mean "normalize the angle into the range [0, 1) such that 0 is 0° and 1 is 360°" but maybe I'm overthinking it.

OP is welcome to reply or edit with a clarification if that is what they meant.
